# Flash Player breaks Safari!

Tags: macos, safari, adobe-flash

As of a few days ago, some Safari webpages (the first and most frequently-occurring of which was Facebook's News Feed) would start loading but then freeze up. I went into Activity Monitor, and while it did say that Safari Web Content wasn't responding, it also said that Flash Player (Safari web plugin) wasn't responding. Force Quitting the Safari Web Content didn't do anything; the page just reloaded and froze up again, but when I forced Flash Player to quit, the misbehaving webpage refreshed and worked perfectly. After several more instances of the problem I uninstalled and reinstalled Flash Player, and the problem happened again.

I've currently got Flash Player uninstalled for stability's sake, but I can't live a Flashless life forever. How can I fix the problem?

UPDATE: It just happened again after I attempted a reinstall. This time, I checked my Flash version.

OS X 10.10.2, Safari 8.0.3, Flash "NPAPI Plug-in version 16.0.0.305 is installed."

Comment: You force-quit the Safari Web Content, but it might also require to quit Safari itself.  Also, Flash has been updated several times in the past few weeks to patch critical security issues.  Can you be more explicit with the version number?  Even if you downloaded it recently, there's a chance that Apple has blocked it from running if it is not the absolute latest.

Comment: @Kent When I force-quit the Safari Web Content, it wouldn't fix the problem. The page would just reload and crash again. The *only* way to get the page to load was to force-quit the unresponsive Flash Player plugin. And about the version numbers, I can't check since Flash is uninstalled now (and I've got a big file download going so I really don't want to quit Safari to reinstall Flash), but the uninstall/reinstall I wrote about happened earlier today. Unless they released another update literally today, there's no way I wouldn't be up to date.

Comment: Ok, regarding the flash player version.  And, IIRC, the flash installer also forces you to quit Safari, right?  If the problem URL is public, can you add it to the question?

Comment: @Kent The most frequently-occurring problem was Facebook. I don't remember what the other sites were.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google's Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome/) browser includes a built-in flash plugin. I uninstalled Flash on my system too but I use Chrome for loading up sites which require flash.

Another tack you might try is to install [Click to Plugin](http://hoyois.github.io/safariextensions/clicktoplugin/). I was going to recommend Click to Flash, but apparently that isn't under development anymore and the developer recommends Click to Plugin.

Comment: Nice ideas! I was hoping to find a way to figure out what was wrong with Flash, but in the meantime, these are some decent workarounds.